# How to change the position of a container again after dragging and dropping it once in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I know how to drag and drop a container but if I place it in a wrong position, I want to undo it but can't seem to find how to do it. Can anyone tell me how to do it in flutter??

Comment: can you please elaborate the question more. Also if you want to place a container at a certain position you can use various ways like put it in a stack and use the positioned widget to align it or you can wrap it inside a row or column and use their mainaxisalignment property. Even you can use the padding property of container itself to have it positioned where you want.

Comment: I have to drag and drop a container from one place to another. I am able to do that but if I drop it at a wrong position by mistake, I cannot undo it. I have to run the dart file again which I don't want to do

Comment: Can you provide the code for the same please...

Comment: What are you using for developing the UI?